# Limiting large array to 1D in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, large-data

I'm working with XShooter data and for galactic corrections, I'm using `ccm_unred` in MATLAB. The problem is

```
funred = flux*10.^(0.4*A_lambda);
```

this line of code generates a `29686 X 29686 double` array. I want only one side of it, I can do it by reassigning `funred` as `funred = funred(:,1)` but this piece of code also takes `57 seconds` to be executed and uses up my CPU and RAM too much for my laptop to stay stable. Is there any method by which I can limit the generation of `funred` to only `(:,1)` from the beginning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that your code generates a 29686 X 29686 matrix, however you are doing element-wise operations in your equation. That means that either `flux` or `A_lambda` bust be 29686 X 29686. Just slice the ones that are that size!

Assuming one of them is 29686 X 29686

```
funred = flux(:,1)*10.^(0.4*A_lambda(:,1));
```

Just remove the `(:,1)` of the one that is is not a matrix.

If both of them are a matices, then you can not do it, as `flux*...` would need the whole matrix to operate.

Comment: There is one matrix manipulation in there, so  though I agree that this works if you have only 1 matrix, I think this is incorrect in the case that they are both matrices. I think you would need `funred = flux*10.^(0.4*A_lambda(:,1))` if both are matrices.

Comment: @AnderBiguri thank you very much. The problem was `A_lambda`, I had two more `funred` lines in code and I was afraid what was going to happen. Time consumption is now `0.8 seconds` :-)

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin yes, the flux was already 29686 X 1 only, but it was a mistake on my part to not indicate that in the question.